# Is there any app that could extract and manage questions from Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, app, questions, python

I'm looking for help with a Stack Overflow application that could do the following things for me:

1. Extract the top voted questions at a given date and tag
2. Extract the answered questions of some given user

Recently, I have created an [`opensource APP`](https://github.com/Bluebird7/poptop) with `scrapy-python` and `PyQt` that could extract and collect the top voted questions at a given date and convert them to **PDF**.

I put it on [Github](https://github.com/Bluebird7/poptop), but as it's in elemental level I think it could be better and developed.
So I ask users, if they have any experience on related subjects and technologies, to feel free and help to improve it!;)